# How to handle HTML with PHP's DOMDocument if the encoding of source HTML is unknown?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, domdocument, mb-convert-encoding

I just faced that HTML document encoded with UTF-8 becomes incorrect after `loadHTML()`.

There are plenty of such QnA's on the Stack:

- [PHP DomDocument failing to handle utf-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309194/php-domdocument-failing-to-handle-utf-8-characters-%E2%98%86)
- [PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)
- [PHP DOM UTF-8 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548880/php-dom-utf-8-problem)

However as I understand most of the answers taking assumption that the source encoding **is** UTF-8. So it is recommended to use `mb_convert_encoding()` function in this way:

```
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($document_in_utf_8, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

I suppose that this will work **only** if the source document **is** in UTF-8. Unfortunately in my world the source document can has any available codding: Windows-1251, UTF-8, KOI8-R and so on...

So what is the best practice to handle this problem for any encoding?

**UPDATE 1**: Just find `mb_detect_encoding()` function. Is it a good practice to use one to detect the encoding? In the way like this:

```
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($doc);
$doc = mb_convert_encoding($doc, 'HTML-ENTITIES', $encoding);
$dom->loadHTML($doc);
```

Tested this on several documents: looks like it working, but can I be sure that this will work for all reasonable cases?