# in DOMDocument why does an "en dash" in a title tag break unicode strings?

Tags: php, unicode, domdocument

why does an "[en dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html)" in a title tag break unicode strings in DOMDocument?
this code

```
<?php
$html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>example.org – example.org - example.org</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>Trädgård</body>
</html>
HTML;
$domd = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
@$domd->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);
$interesting = $domd->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->textContent;
var_dump($interesting, bin2hex($interesting));
```

prints the nonsense

```
string(14) "TrÃ¤dgÃ¥rd"
string(28) "5472c383c2a46467c383c2a57264"
```

however if we just remove the en-dash from line 5, change it to

```
    <title>example.org example.org - example.org</title>
```

it prints

```
string(10) "Trädgård"
string(20) "5472c3a46467c3a57264"
```

so why does en-dash break unicode strings in DOMDocument?

(took me a long time to track down that the en-dash is the cause x.x )

Comment: what is `<head a>`? random stray attribute or something missing?

Comment: Do you control the HTML? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in place of `<meta charset="utf-8" />` resolves the issue... from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548880/php-dom-utf-8-problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218649/3859027 answer here already works fine

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius leftover from trying to track down why unicode strings were breaking, ignore it

Comment: @user3783243 no i don't :(

Comment: @hanshenrik `str_replace('<meta charset="utf-8" />', '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />', $rawhtml)` maybe? That assumes you always have the same meta charset format though

Answer (score 1):

don't know why, exactly, but the key here seems to be that *any* unicode characters occurring before the utf-8 declaration will confuse it, meaning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>æøå</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>Trädgård</body>
</html>
```

will confuse it, while

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>æøå</title>
</head>
<body>Trädgård</body>
</html>
```

works fine.. and @Tino Didriksen found this quote from  https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations

> so it's best to put it immediately after the opening head tag.

and.. as the top rated comment in the [loadHTML documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251) mentions, a quick'n dirty workaround is

```
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);
```